# Primary key design and partitioning for large sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, primary-key

I'm currently designing a database for sql server and I need to handle a large set of datas.

The context is the following one I have : 
substrats composed of 4680 chips as a unique ID
each chip is composed of 66 spots and has a pass/fail boolean
each spot as 3 values (x,y,radius)

So every 20 minutes I need to insert 1 substrat wich correspond to 308'880 spots and this 24/24h 7/7d for 10 years resulting in  8bn spots (I know it sounds a lot..)

I thought about using composite key like this :
**SUBSTRAT**(INT ID)
**CHIP**(INT FK_SUBSTRATID, ROWNUMBER INT, COLNUMBER INT)
**SPOT**(INT FK_SUBSTRATID, CHIPROWNUMBER INT, CHIPCOLNUMBER INT ,ROWNUMBER INT,COLNUMBER INT )

The column number and row number iterate from 1-30 for chips and spots
I'm also thinking about putting all the spots informations into the CHIP table. I don't really know what's best in case like this as I never encountered such an amount of datas.

I'm wondering how I could use partitionning on those tables, the datas need to be available with a good response time for let say 30 days, so I was planning on adding a field  InsertDate to do partitioning on it.

**EDIT :**
As for the use of the data, the chip information will be used within the 30 days to make decision as wether or not the manufacturing of the substrat should go on.
The spot information will be used to do statistical analysis of x,y deviation on demand
The spot and chip informations should be retrieved on demand for at least 10 years
All of the datas needs to be kept for compliance with FDA requirements

Thank you all for your advices

Comment: One important piece of information which is there is that data is added for every chip every 20 mins (if I understood correctly). Any design will need to take into account the fact that significant fragmentation may occur unless the clustered index is such that new records are added to the end. This may be OK if you have a large amount of padding on the index and regular maintenance to rebuild it.

Comment: @AndyNichols Yes you understood it clearly the 4680 chips and 308'880 spots are added at once every 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'll defer to others on your main question of key design, but wanted to answer on the issue of insert and read performance.

When you need to both write and read large data sets efficiently then it can be a good time to use seperate dedicated read and write databases.  The idea is that you have two different schemas--one optimized for rapid writing, one optimized for rapid reading.  You then put together jobs which work through the input data and move it over to the readable database/tables.  The trade-off is that your written data isn't immediately available (the lag depends on how you prefer to process the writes).

The approach is similar (but not exactly) [Command Query Responsibility Segregation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html)--CQRS.  The gist is that having specialized read vs write components can let each be highly tuned to its role.